# Updating Firmware

Tags: firmware

I've bought a new computer a few days ago and installed 23.04 onto it.
Now I need to look into firmware & drivers to make sure it is all up to date.

With Ubuntu, all the drivers come from the kernel (at least in my case they did).
The bios can be had from the motherboard manufacturer(asus) and can be flashed within bios.
But the Intel ME firmware can't be done in bios.. at least not that I can see.

How do linux users update the ME without resorting to windows?

Comment: I purchased the *dell* box I'm using back in February 2023; and installed Ubuntu on it...  I've been told of firmware updates at least twice between then & now, and Ubuntu has performed those upgrades for my system.  They do require me to reboot (*they apply on next boot with my seeing the dell upgrade in progress screens slowing the 'boot' process*), so they tend to sit a number of days (*I usually reboot only once per fornight*) but I did nothing with my Ubuntu Desktop install.

Comment: `Now I need to look into firmware & drivers to make sure it is all up to date.` - If everything works, then you don't have to do anything. Ubuntu installs the necessary drivers anyway.

Comment: It is more the the Intel ME updates that I am concerned about. Drivers and device firmware are ok & bios can be updated in bios. but the Intel ME firmware has me stuck.

Comment: depending on the brand of your computer you my be stuck with windows exe or msi format to upgrade bios or firmware, in that case one can try a windows bootable usb key with just the needed msi/exe to upgrade.